# Can a multicore system allow two or more cores to simultaneously access the same memory location?

Tags: arm, smp

I am currently studying the ARM architecture. Can two cores on a multicore system simultaneously access the same memory location?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "simultaneously". In a practical sense: Yes. (In a strict sense: No.)

Comment: By simulatenousy I mean exactly at the same time i.e. at the same clock pulses.

Comment: In all senses, it depends.  If you have dual port DRAM and hook up separate ARM buses to each side of the chip, then you can.  It all depends on the system, the OS, the particular ARM chip, etc.  You need to research [memory coherency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_coherence).  The solution is different for different ARM versions (and even within the ARM version).  Even if the system supports it, the OS can make it impossible.  Generally, a single write or read (past caches) is atomic.  A read/modify/write is system dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Along with other docs you will need (architectural reference, technical reference).  Get the AMBA/AXI manual from arm (infocenter.arm.com).  It shows how the bus works.  Obviously you cant access the same memory location at the same time but each core can have more than one transaction in flight and you can certainly have multiple transactions in flight for the same address.

Now caching comes into play as well you may end up with one or both accessing its local cache and not the shared memory location.

the ldrex/strex pair was added specifically for this problem of multiple cores accessing the same location.

Answer (score 0):

yes if they only read from that location. when that location is written to then the cache needs to invalidate that location in order to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

They can. However, you should avoid this at all costs since the performance will be unbearable due to the cache coherency issues.